# Sign problem when working out a simple pendulum's differential equation

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was trying to work out the differential equation for a simple pendulum,  and got  a sign mistake along the way (among other things I guess). Here's my reasoning:

assuming that the friction forces are negligible, one may use the conservation of energy principle. When $\theta(t)=\theta_0$ (position 1), we have

$E_{mech_1}=U_1$ $\quad$ (since $K_1=0$)

and that at the equilibrium point (position 2)

$E_{mech_2}=K_2$ $\quad$ (since $U_2=0$)

and therefore

$K_2=U_1 \iff  \frac{1}{2}mL^2\dot{\theta}^2\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}mgL(1-\cos\theta)=0.$

It does however make sense to me that ([ref.](https://studylib.net/doc/18369787/the-simple-plane-pendulum))

$E_{mech}=U+K$

but I don't really see my mistake. Is it my interpretation of the potential $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as
$$
K_2=U_1 \iff  \frac{1}{2}mL^2\dot{\theta_2}^2\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}mgL(1-\cos\theta_1)=0,
$$
then it is correct. You are computing the relation of maximum angle and maximal velocity, these events happen at different positions, as you also wrote above.